# Apple Open Source developer libraries

Tags: c, macos, cmake

have run into a problem lately where I was looking for a particular header file. I couldn't find it anywhere until I stumbled across it's source in a google search which lead me to this site:

http://opensource.apple.com/release/mac-os-x-1068/

My question: Are these projects that are supposed to be downloaded separately, one at a time, to be used on OSX, or are they supposed to be already included with some developer package of OSX? I am a new OSX user, and all I know presently is that I have xcode on the box, but seem to be missing some libs that my code (given to me) is looking for.

Here is what my cmake file looks like:

```
project(myproject)
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
SET(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE debug)
SET(CMAKE_C_FLAGS_DEBUG "-g -fPIC -O0 -pipe -std=c99")
SET(CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE TRUE)
file(GLOB HEADER_LIST ./include/*.h)
include_directories(./include)
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SRC_LIST} ${HEADER_LIST})
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} -lpcap)
```

and my source file has

```
#include <net/bpf.h>
#include <pcap.h>
```

however, I am getting some errors with trying to use the structures that are supposed to be in pcap not being defined. Should I pull pcap separately from this apple open source lib, or as a part of a bigger package?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT: Your problem is that you're relying on a private, internal data structure. `pcap-int.h` is not provided because it is not part of the public API.

---

Most library headers (including pcap) are available in `/usr/include`, though typically you link them from the developer SDKs so that you can control the specific version you're building against. To include and link with the correct headers and libraries using cmake, you generally use the `CMAKE_OSX_SYSROOT` variable. You control the deployment target with `CMAKE_OSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET`. For example, here is an old one of mine:

```
set(CMAKE_OSX_SYSROOT "/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.5.sdk")
set(CMAKE_OSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 10.4)
```

The latest versions of Xcode are no longer in `/Developer`, so you would need to point into `/Applications/Xcode.app`. You can get the correct path using:

```
xcode-select -print-path
```

Not everything on opensource.apple.com is available in the SDKs directly. Some things are private. You could install them from opensource.apple.com, though I've often found that they won't correctly build that way (you often wind up having to install a lot of other packages from Apple and it gets to be a headache). If you need something like that, it's often much easier to just install the "normal" version and statically link it into your program.

But pcap should work fine. What problem are you actually seeing?

Comment: I have included the files <net/bpf.h> and <pcap.h> and I have a variable `pcap_t *pd;` and when i try to use it `pd->fd;` i get `dereferencing pointer to incomplete type` which I am not sure is because I am not having the right includes, or my CmakeLists.txt is bad

Comment: edited my question to include my cmake file. I am new to Cmake, so I am not sure if I am doing it correctly

Comment: The pcap structure is private. You shouldn't be relying on internal headers like `pcap-int.h`. See pcap(3) for the public interface.

Comment: Can you elaborate or point me to what you mean? I am editing existing code here that I did not develop, and that developer is long gone, so I am trying to decipher what is being done

Comment: Your reference to `pd->fd` is a private, internal data structure of pcap. The former developer should never have used things that were not available in `pcap.h`. Your best approach is to rework the code to use only things available in `pcap.h`. If this is impossible, then you can copy the `struct` definition into your implementation code (rather than the entire header file), but this is very fragile. Private data structures are private for a reason.

Answer (score 1):

They're not necessarily "to be used on OSX", they **are** MacOS X. The heart of MacOS X is Darwin, and Apple makes the source code for Darwin available via http://opensource.apple.com. You can look at those projects to see how Darwin works. You can modify them and build your own version of Darwin. You can use the code in your own projects if you find it applicable (subject to the terms of the license attached to whatever component you're looking at).

Comment: I guess the end of your answer is what I am getting at - I am trying to work on some BSD code, and the library seems to be missing from OSX. I wasn't sure if, since it's the "heart of MacOS X" that it should already be there, or if they expected developers to check the repo. for the appropriate project and install it

Comment: I've got a `libpcap` on my (Lion) machine. Look in `/usr/lib` for `libpcap.dylib`.

Comment: I see that file as well, however, the file that seems to be missing is pcap-int.h which I need I think because I am getting that "dereferencing pointer" error on the pcap_t pointer (which is of type pcap defined in that header file) see: http://opensource.apple.com/source/libpcap/libpcap-11/libpcap/pcap-int.h

Answer (score 1):

OS X is released without the header files needed to build components.  A vanilla 10.7 OS X does not even have a `/usr/include` directory.  Downloading `Xcode` is the first step.  Then you either need to install the `Command Line Tools` option (`Preferences` -> `Downloads` -> `Components`) within Xcode to install the headers or you need to ensure your project's build system uses the SDKs provided by Xcode.  If you don't need the Xcode IDE, you can now also download the `Command Line Tools` component of Xcode 4.3 separately from the Apple Developer Connection web site.